# How to pad rows and columns of a two dimension array with Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have a two-dimensional array which I need to grow depending on certain conditions.

The array can grow including new rows before the first existing and / or after the last one existing, the same for the columns.

The values of the array represent fixed physical positions between rows and columns of a grid so when the array grows the existing values must remain in the same physical position but with a new position in the array.

I have been able to find some examples for Java and Python but these examples use libraries without access to their source code so I can not duplicate the algorithm used.

An example of what is needed would be:
Original Array (4x6):

[array table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCgip.png)

Ejemplo de crecimiento:
Desde (4x6) a (8x7):

[new array table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKH1z.png)

A example with Python:

[array pad with Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XheW.png)

Explanation:
The array will grow four rows, two before the first original [0,0] and two after the last original [3,0] and one column before the first original column, this defines the new position for both values as: [ 0.0] to [2,1] and [3,0] to [5,1].

Each element of the array represents a value of type double, but this is irrelevant to the design since it is possible to use another type of data for each element.

The scenario is as follows: we have data from a particular area, divided by a grid and each data represents a value of one of the cells in the grid. Subsequently, new data is obtained from another area located in the same sector but of a larger size. To represent all the data obtained, a grid is defined that covers the entire area sampled, that is, the edges of the grid are defined by the external positions of each area, giving that the grid represents the surrounding rectangle of all the areas.

Each cell of each grid represents a fixed geographical position, so it must remain in the same geographic position independent of the size of the grid that contains them. The values of the grid representing the entire sampled area represent mathematical operations between the sampled values in the same geographical position. This means the event that the array must grow since each grid is stored in an array that represents each sampled position.

This means that a value located in a particular position (cell) of the sampling grid has a position with different indices in the grid that represents the entire sampling area; each grid has its own left corner 0,0.

Comment: You will want to use a 2D dynamic array (array of array of element). When you grow a dynamic array, you define the new extent and elements will be added to the end, so you will need to move previous elements, if you need to "insert" to the beginning.

Comment: If I understand the basic form but, my arrays are around 25000 to 40000 elements or more, that's why I'm looking for if there is some more efficient algorithm that just enlarge and move, as it is in Java and Phyton as in C #

Comment: Perhaps you should add actual magnitudes of the dimansions to your question and also element type. Btw, what is the syntax in the mentioned languages for growing by inserting unused elements as you describe? How do you know that the algorithms in those languages are more efficient than enlarge and move? Anyway, main point is to minimize the need for re-allocation, start with e.g. 10000 elements, then grow to the double and again to double for 40000 elements.

Comment: Btw, what does this mean: *...so when the array grows the existing values must remain in the same physical position but with a new position in the array*? What is the physical position you are talking about?

Comment: You could implement this in any number of ways, for example an array of arrays that you extend with something like SetLength and then move elements about, or you could use a double linked matrix where elements are allocated on the heap and manipulated as a linked list or you could use a coordinate list where each element not only contain the value, but also it's position in the matrix (and many many others). However, without understanding your design goals - must it run fast - must is save space etc, it is difficult to recommend a good solution.

Comment: There are no data structures part of Delphi's standard units that will allow you to do this easily. I haven't seen them in neither C# nor Java, but I may just be ignorant.

Comment: I have included an explanation of the basic values and operations of the idea

Comment: How often do you increase the number of columns ?. Because if it's not very often, then you could store your numbers consecutively on an oversized buffer and use a center window on it. When you want to add rows at the start or end, you expand your use window accordingly. Only when you reach the bounds of the buffer you will need to create a new bigger buffer and copy your data on it. Also, when you add more columns you will also need to create a new buffer (probably bigger) and copy your data. This way it will only be slow when changing the number of columns or when you run out of your buffer.

Comment: Since you are getting new data once each area have been sampled why don't you store data for each area in a separate array. You can calculate world position for any area point by adding the local cell position with area world offset. This way you avoid the need for having one huge array for entire world which could theoretically even lead to OutOfMemory exceptions since an array needs to be in a continuous block of memory which may not be available due to memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is using Lists instead of Arrays, so you can insert rows and columns both at the start and the end of those lists. To simplify the code I have provided the solution using Generics (Delphi 2009 and posteriors).

It would be very similar than how you already work with Array of Arrays. Your matrix type would be (at Andreas suggestion I have replaced the outer TList by a TObjectList, so you don't need to manually free the inner TLists) :

```
TObjectList<TList<integer>>
```

Reading/changing your TLists matrix is as simple as if they were arrays. The element (i,j) is :

```
Matrix[i][j]
```

To add rows at the start you would use :

```
Matrix.Insert(0, TList<integer>.Create);
```

At the end would be :

```
Matrix.Add(TList<integer>.Create);
```

To add columns at the start you would use :

```
var Row: TList<integer>;
begin
  for Row in Matrix do Row.Insert(0, 0);
end;
```

And to add them at the end would be :

```
var Row: TList<integer>;
begin
  for Row in Matrix do Row.Add(0);
end;
```

Remember that at the end you will need to free these objects.

```
Matrix.Free;
```

I have created a sample project to test it. This is the dfm :

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 48
    Top = 141
    Width = 21
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Row'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 119
    Top = 141
    Width = 15
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Col'
  end
  object btnAddRowStart: TButton
    Left = 38
    Top = 32
    Width = 96
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Add Row at Start'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = btnAddRowStartClick
  end
  object btnAddRowEnd: TButton
    Left = 38
    Top = 63
    Width = 96
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Add Row at End'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = btnAddRowEndClick
  end
  object btnAddColStart: TButton
    Left = 145
    Top = 32
    Width = 96
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Add Col at Start'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = btnAddColStartClick
  end
  object btnAddColEnd: TButton
    Left = 145
    Top = 63
    Width = 96
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Add Colt at End'
    TabOrder = 3
    OnClick = btnAddColEndClick
  end
  object btnReadValue: TButton
    Left = 207
    Top = 158
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Read Value'
    TabOrder = 6
    OnClick = btnReadValueClick
  end
  object btnSetValue: TButton
    Left = 207
    Top = 189
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Set Value'
    TabOrder = 7
    OnClick = btnSetValueClick
  end
  object txtRow: TEdit
    Left = 48
    Top = 160
    Width = 65
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 4
    Text = '1'
  end
  object txtCol: TEdit
    Left = 119
    Top = 160
    Width = 66
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 5
    Text = '1'
  end
  object txtReadValue: TEdit
    Left = 296
    Top = 160
    Width = 65
    Height = 21
    Enabled = False
    TabOrder = 8
    Text = '1'
  end
  object txtSetValue: TEdit
    Left = 296
    Top = 191
    Width = 65
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 9
    Text = '1'
  end
end
```

And the code :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnAddRowStart: TButton;
    btnAddRowEnd: TButton;
    btnAddColStart: TButton;
    btnAddColEnd: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    btnReadValue: TButton;
    btnSetValue: TButton;
    txtRow: TEdit;
    txtCol: TEdit;
    txtReadValue: TEdit;
    txtSetValue: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAddRowStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAddRowEndClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAddColStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAddColEndClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnReadValueClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSetValueClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Matrix: TObjectList<TList<integer>>;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Matrix := TObjectList<TList<integer>>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Matrix.Free;
end;    

procedure TForm1.btnReadValueClick(Sender: TObject);
var i, j: integer;
begin
  i := StrToInt(txtRow.Text);
  j := StrToInt(txtCol.Text);

  txtReadValue.Text := Matrix[i][j].ToString;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnSetValueClick(Sender: TObject);
var i, j: integer;
begin
  i := StrToInt(txtRow.Text);
  j := StrToInt(txtCol.Text);

  Matrix[i][j] := StrToInt(txtSetValue.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddRowStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Matrix.Insert(0, TList<integer>.Create);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddRowEndClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Matrix.Add(TList<integer>.Create);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddColStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var Row: TList<integer>;
begin
  for Row in Matrix do Row.Insert(0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddColEndClick(Sender: TObject);
var Row: TList<integer>;
begin
  for Row in Matrix do Row.Add(0);
end;

end.
```

Comment: But of course you now need to manage object lifetimes manually. For instance, if you remove a row, you also need to free the `TList` object. It might arguably be better to use a `TObjectList` instead of a `TList` for the rows, so it can handle that part for you. (And of course, when you no longer need `Matrix`, you should free it. You could hint about that by doing it in the form's `OnDestroy` handler.)

Comment: Also notice that there are _many_ ways to achieve the OP's goal. Using a list of list objects is only one of them. You could also use a two-dimensional dynamic array, or a _single_ array with all values (together with an integer specifying the length of each row). In either case, you need to choose between row-major and column-major order. Ultimately, what determines which approach is the "best" one is how the matrix will be used in practice. (Which matrix operations do you need to be fast?)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks, I have update the answer to include the freeing of the object. Indeed, there are many ways to solve this problem, I have provided this one because it seems to me very straightforward.

Comment: I agree that for pedagogical reasons, this approach is the one to focus on when answering a question like this one.

Comment: I have already made an implementation with DataSets with records containing the coordinates of each element and the respective value, a simpler alternative than the one proposed. The problem is in the speed of iteration of the records, when we compare 45000 records against 20,000 others, the loop takes too many seconds, almost minutes. In addition, the system is dynamic which means that the comparisons can be made several times in a row, for this reason I am in search of a more efficient alternative and that does not block the application by making the calculations.

Comment: Each grid sampled is permanent, it is not replaced or deleted until the program is finished, the grid-matrix-array-list that should grow would contain the results of geometrical operations between the contents of the different grids, only the values that are present in each grid, in the same location, are calculated.

Comment: @Fisad I believe that a solution with Lists would iterate your data faster, but about the datasets, have you added an in-memory index to your dataset to iterate it quickly ? (not all kind of datasets support it, but for example the FDMemTable supports them).

Comment: @Marc Guillot The problem I see with the lists is that if, for example, I add 100 rows and 3 columns I will have to make 100 aggregations of rows and as many aggregations of columns (3 times) as so many rows already exist in the matrix. As a fast and efficient alternative in memory I am working in the creation of two classes, a class that will store the calculation information between grid-matrices, the total grid and a class for the grids which will store the information of each individual grid and the 4 offset in reference to the total grid.

Comment: I already use indexes for the DataSets, I have compared them with arrays and lists in memory, but what I want is to avoid iteration between non-overlay grid positions, without having to search them one by one in the reference DataSets.